# Why my UITableView does not work anymore?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This table worked until I added 2 empty cells.
I don't know what happened, but now I can't understand what did I miss.
I posted all the `"SchedaVolontario.swift"` code, in this way you can analyze all the code.

As you can see I used `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` method with `indexPath` constructor.

```
 //  SchedaVolontario.swift

    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FlexibleSteppedProgressBar

    class SchedaVolontario: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FlexibleSteppedProgressBarDelegate {


        let userCalendar = Calendar.current

        let requestedComponent: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day,.hour,.minute,.second,.month]

        var codvolontario : String?
        var nome: String?
        var cognome : String?
        var sede : String?
        var progetto : String?
        var datainizioservizio : String?
        var datafineservizio : String?
        var spazio: String?
        var licenze : String?
        var malattie : String?
        var monitoraggio_uno : String?
        var monitoraggio_due : String?
        var monitoraggio_tre : String?
        var progressBar: FlexibleSteppedProgressBar!
        var monitoraggiostep = 0
        var maxIndex = -1
        // dichiarazione tabella di riferimento
        @IBOutlet weak var guestInfoTableView: UITableView!

        //dichiarazione array celle
        var guestInfoList: [String] = []

        //dichiarazione array celle
        var test: [String] = []

        //Dichairazione variabili generali per l'esecuzione di routine di calcolo

        var labName: UILabel?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            //aggiorna cella monitoraggio
            ricalcolaCellaMonitoraggio()
            //avvia funzione riempimento celle
            populateGuestInfoList()
            //configurazione countdown
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ricalcolaCellaCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            //delegate and datasource
            guestInfoTableView.delegate = self
            guestInfoTableView.dataSource = self
        }


        //riempimento celle
        func populateGuestInfoList() {

            //Nome
            if codvolontario != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("")
            }

            //Cognome
            if codvolontario != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("")
            }

            //Codice volontario
            if codvolontario != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("Il mio Codice Volontario:                     \(codvolontario!)")
            }

            //void1
            if codvolontario != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("")
            }

            //Ente
            if sede != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("Dove svolgo il mio servizio civile:")
            }

            //Descrizione ente
            if let sede = sede {
                guestInfoList.append(sede)
            }

            //Progetto
            if progetto != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("Il mio progetto:")
            }


            //Descrizione titolo progetto
            if let progetto = progetto {
                guestInfoList.append(progetto)
            }

            //void2
            if codvolontario != nil {
                guestInfoList.append("")
            }

            //Tempo
            if spazio == spazio {
                guestInfoList.append("Quanto manca alla fine del mio progetto:")
            }
            //creazione cella vuota per il countdown
            if spazio == spazio {
                guestInfoList.append("")
    }

            //Data inizio
            if  let datainizioservizio = datainizioservizio {
                guestInfoList.append("\(datainizioservizio)")

            }

            //Data fine
            if let datafineservizio = datafineservizio {
                guestInfoList.append("\(datafineservizio)")
            }

            //Monitoraggio
            if  monitoraggio_uno == monitoraggio_uno {
                guestInfoList.append("")
            }


        }



        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return guestInfoList.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            //Nome
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let nomecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nomecell", for: indexPath)
                var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                let myString: NSString = "Nome:                                                     \(nome!)" as NSString
                myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
                myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:5))
                // set label Attribute
                labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
                nomecell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
                nomecell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
                nomecell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
            }

            //Cognome
            if indexPath.row == 1 {
                let cognomecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cognomecell", for: indexPath)
                var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                let myString: NSString = "Cognome:                                              \(cognome!)" as NSString
                myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
                myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:8))
                // set label Attribute
                labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
                cognomecell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
                cognomecell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
            }

            //codvolcell
            if indexPath.row == 2 {
                let codvolcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "codvolcell", for: indexPath)
                var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                let myString: NSString = "Il mio Codice Volontario:                     \(codvolontario!)" as NSString
                myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
                myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:25))
                // set label Attribute
                labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
                codvolcell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
                codvolcell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
            }

            //distacco 1
            if indexPath.row == 3 {
                let voidcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "voidcell", for: indexPath)
                voidcell.textLabel?.text = ""
            }

            //Ente
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                let entecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "entecell", for: indexPath)
                entecell.textLabel?.text = "Dove svolgo il mio servizio civile:"
                let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                if let aFont = myFont {
                    entecell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                    entecell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
                }
            }

            //Descrizione ente
            if indexPath.row == 5 {
                let sedecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sedecell", for: indexPath)
                sedecell.textLabel?.text = sede
                let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                if let aFont = myFont {
                    sedecell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                }
            }

            //Progetto
            if indexPath.row == 6 {
                let progettocell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "progettocell", for: indexPath)
                progettocell.textLabel?.text = "Il mio progetto:"
                let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                if let aFont = myFont {
                    progettocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                    progettocell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
                }
            }

            //Descrizione titolo progetto
            if indexPath.row == 7 {
                let titolocell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "titolocell", for: indexPath)
                titolocell.textLabel?.text = progetto
                let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                if let aFont = myFont {
                    titolocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                }
            }

            //distacco 2
            if indexPath.row == 8 {
                let voidcell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "voidcell2", for: indexPath)
                voidcell2.textLabel?.text = ""
            }

            //Tempo residuo alla fine del SC
            if indexPath.row == 9 {
                let tempocell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tempocell", for: indexPath)
                tempocell.textLabel?.text = "Quanto manca alla fine del mio progetto:"
                let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                if let aFont = myFont {
                    tempocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                    tempocell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
                }
            }

            //countdown
            let countdowncell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countdowncell", for: indexPath)
            if indexPath.row == 10 {
                let countdowncell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "countdowncell", for: indexPath)
                countdowncell.textLabel?.text = calcolaCountdown()
            }else{
                countdowncell.textLabel?.text = guestInfoList[indexPath.row]
            }


            //Data inizio servizio civile
            if indexPath.row == 11 {
                let datainiziocell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "datainiziocell", for: indexPath)
                var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                let myString: NSString = "Data inizio del mio servizio civile:                 \(datainizioservizio!)" as NSString
                myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
                myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:36))
                // set label Attribute
                labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
                datainiziocell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
                datainiziocell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
                datainiziocell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
            }

            //Data fine servizio civile
            if indexPath.row == 12 {
                let datafinecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "datafinecell", for: indexPath)
                var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                let myString: NSString = "Data fine del mio servizio civile:                 \(datafineservizio!)" as NSString
                myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
                myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:34))
                // set label Attribute
                labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
                datafinecell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
                datafinecell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
            }

            //Stampa Monitoraggio
            if indexPath.row == 13 {
            let monitoraggiocell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monitoraggiocell", for: indexPath)

                if monitoraggio_tre ==  "OK" {
                    monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.text = "3° Monitoraggio disponibile"
                    let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                    if let aFont = myFont {
                        monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                    }
                    monitoraggiostep = 2
                    let myFirstButton = UIButton()
                    myFirstButton.setTitle(" ", for: .normal)
                    myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
                    myFirstButton.frame = CGRect(x: 345, y: 575, width: 10, height: 10)
                    myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                    self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
                }
                else {
                    if monitoraggio_due == "OK" {
                        monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.text = "2° Monitoraggio disponibile"
                        let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                        if let aFont = myFont {
                            monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                        }
                        monitoraggiostep = 1
                        let myFirstButton = UIButton()
                        myFirstButton.setTitle(" ", for: .normal)
                        myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
                        myFirstButton.frame = CGRect(x: 290, y: 575, width: 10, height: 10)
                        myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                        self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
                    }


                    else {
                        if monitoraggio_uno == "OK" {
                            monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.text = "1° Monitoraggio disponibile"
                            let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                            if let aFont = myFont {
                                monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                            }
                            monitoraggiostep = 0
                            let myFirstButton = UIButton()
                            myFirstButton.setTitle(" ", for: .normal)
                            myFirstButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
                            myFirstButton.frame = CGRect(x: 236, y: 575, width: 10, height: 10)
                            myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                            self.view.addSubview(myFirstButton)
                        }
                        else {
                            if monitoraggio_uno != "OK" {
                                monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.text = "Nessun monitoraggio disponibile"
                                let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)
                                if let aFont = myFont {
                                    monitoraggiocell.textLabel?.font = aFont
                                }
                            monitoraggiostep = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
                //Configurazioni grafiche
                progressBar = FlexibleSteppedProgressBar()
                progressBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                progressBar.numberOfPoints = 3
                progressBar.lineHeight = 9
                progressBar.radius = 15
                progressBar.progressRadius = 25
                progressBar.progressLineHeight = 3
                progressBar.delegate = self
                progressBar.useLastState = true
                progressBar.selectedBackgoundColor = UIColor.green
                progressBar.selectedOuterCircleStrokeColor = UIColor.red
                progressBar.lastStateOuterCircleStrokeColor = UIColor.red
                progressBar.centerLayerDarkBackgroundTextColor = UIColor.red
                progressBar.currentSelectedCenterColor = UIColor.red
                //imposta valore monitoraggio
                progressBar.completedTillIndex = monitoraggiostep
                progressBar.currentIndex = monitoraggiostep
                //inserimento e posizionamento
                progressBar.frame = CGRect(x: 230, y: 11, width: 130, height: 20)
                monitoraggiocell.contentView.addSubview(progressBar)
            }

            return countdowncell
        }


        //Calcolo Countdown
        func calcolaCountdown() -> String!
        {
            var test = ""
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
            let startTime = Date()
            let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: datafineservizio!)
            let timeDifference = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponent, from: startTime, to: endTime!)
            let dateLabelOutlet = "\(timeDifference.month!) Mesi \(timeDifference.day!) Giorni \(timeDifference.hour!) Ore \(timeDifference.minute!) Minuti \(timeDifference.second!) Secondi"
            if timeDifference.second! < 0 {
                test = "Servizio terminato"
            }
            else {
                test = dateLabelOutlet
            }
            return test
        }
        func ricalcolaCellaCountdown(){
            let indexPathCountdown = IndexPath(row: 10, section: 0)
            guestInfoTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathCountdown], with: .none)
        }
        func ricalcolaCellaMonitoraggio(){
            let indexPathCountdown = IndexPath(row: 13, section: 0)
            guestInfoTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathCountdown], with: .none)
        }

        @objc func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.amesci.org/mobile/serviziocivile/monitoraggio.htm") else {
                return //be safe
            }

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }

        }

        //Generazione Barra di caricamento del monitoraggio
        func progressBar(_ progressBar: FlexibleSteppedProgressBar,
                         didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
            progressBar.currentIndex = index
            if index > maxIndex {
                maxIndex = index
                progressBar.completedTillIndex = maxIndex
            }
        }


        func progressBar(_ progressBar: FlexibleSteppedProgressBar,
                         canSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) -> Bool {
            return false
        }
        //rinomina valore step monitoraggio
        func progressBar(_ progressBar: FlexibleSteppedProgressBar,
                         textAtIndex index: Int, position: FlexibleSteppedProgressBarTextLocation) -> String {
            if progressBar == self.progressBar {
                if position == FlexibleSteppedProgressBarTextLocation.center {
                    switch index {
                    case 0: return "1"
                    case 1: return "2"
                    case 2: return "3"
                    default: return "0"
                    }
                }
            }
            return ""
        }


    }
```

**This is my main table configuration:**

[image: Main.storyboard]

---

**Edit**

This is what does show console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path). Cell identifier: countdowncell, index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x604000038760> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
```

---

**Edit**

I casted each cell in `if/else` statement as Larme suggest me to do... the result is the same. here the snippet and the chatlog, maybe I still not understand:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    //Nome
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let nomecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nomecell", for: indexPath)
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        let myString: NSString = "Nome:                                                     \(nome!)" as NSString
        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:5))
        // set label Attribute
        labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
        nomecell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        nomecell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
        nomecell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
    }
    else {
    //Cognome
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cognomecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cognomecell", for: indexPath)
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        let myString: NSString = "Cognome:                                              \(cognome!)" as NSString
        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:8))
        // set label Attribute
        labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
        cognomecell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
        cognomecell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
    }
    else {
    //codvolcell
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let codvolcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "codvolcell", for: indexPath)
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        let myString: NSString = "Il mio Codice Volontario:                     \(codvolontario!)" as NSString
        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0,length:25))
        // set label Attribute
        labName?.attributedText = myMutableString
        codvolcell.textLabel?.text = myString as String?
        codvolcell.textLabel?.attributedText = myMutableString
    }
    else {

       ...

        monitoraggiocell.contentView.addSubview(progressBar)
    }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
        }
    }
    let the_chosen_one = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nomecell", for: indexPath)
    return the_chosen_one
}
```

**chatlog:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path). Cell identifier: nomecell, index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x6000008244e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
```

---

**Edit**

I solved by rewriting from zero all the table. Guys remember: Save ever a backup copy of your project! This saved me:

Apparently I setted on `Main.storyboard` one more cell than declared by code.

Comment: Unrelated but the code in `cellForRowAt` is very, very inefficient. Use a `switch` for `indexPath` or at least an `if - else if` expression.

Comment: You dequeue more than one cell (each time you deueue the countdown at least), that's what says the error message. Also, you don't seem to return cells except the countdown one.

Comment: Yes, so how can I solve this problem? I need all that cells

Comment: By avoid this and doing `if/else if` not only `if`, and returning the correct cell too.

Comment: See edits, I solved.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have set/assign datasource and delegate for your table. Reload your table, when your array `guestInfoList` has some value/elements.

Try this and see:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //aggiorna cella monitoraggio
    ricalcolaCellaMonitoraggio()
    //avvia funzione riempimento celle
    populateGuestInfoList()
    //configurazione countdown
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ricalcolaCellaCountdown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


     // delegate and datasource
     guestInfoTableView.delegate = self
     guestInfoTableView.dataSource = self


}
```

Comment: that's strange... an error occourred 'guestInfoTableView.datasource': value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'datasource'

Comment: datasource -> dataSource

Comment: Look at here: [UITableView dataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614955-datasource)

Comment: Right... i did yet declared delegate and datasource on class opening

Comment: Do exact, according to code I've shared here. it will work.

Comment: Yes, now I have no more errors, but... another Problem income: See edits

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
guestInfoTableView.dataSource = self
guestInfoTableView.delegate = self
```